# Correct syntax for using a class method as a std::function parameter?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and trying to use an existing library ("WebServer").

I guess the language supports what I'm trying to do. I'm wrestling with getting the syntax right.

I'm struggling with correctly setting up a parameter which has type `std::function<void(void)>`.

In the snippets below, `WebServer` is the library class. I'm trying to use its "on" method, which requires a parameter of type `THandlerFunction`.

The compiler throws errors when I try to setup the `THandlerFunction` parameter and assign it to `fhandleRootPageRequest`.

Some similar-sounding problems suggested using `std::mem_fn()`. `std::mem_fn` looks promising. However, I'm getting some confusing compiler error messages back.

How do I correctly setup `fhandleRootPageRequest`, so I can call `WebServer::on` with its `THandlerFunction` parameter pointing to method `WebServerInterface::handleRootPageRequest`?

```
class WebServer {
public:

    typedef std::function<void(void)> THandlerFunction;
    void on(const Uri& uri, THandlerFunction fn);
    ...
};

...

class WebServerInterface {
public:
    WebServerInterface() {};

    void begin() {
        WebServer::THandlerFunction fhandleRootPageRequest = &WebServerInterface::handleRootPageRequest; // Does not compile
        webServerCPP.on("/", fhandleRootPageRequest);
    }

    void handleRootPageRequest() {
        webServerCPP.send(200, "text/html", "<!doctype html> <html> <head> <body> <div> <h1>Hello World</h1> </div> </body> </html>");

private:
    WebServer webServerCPP;

    }
};
```

```
// Examples of what I've tried. Variations on the fhandleRootPageRequest theme. Do not compile.
WebServer::THandlerFunction fhandleRootPageRequest = &WebServerInterface::handleRootPageRequest; 
    //  error: conversion from 'void (WebServerInterface::*)()' to non-scalar type 'WebServer::THandlerFunction' {aka 'std::function<void()>'} requested

WebServer::THandlerFunction fhandleRootPageRequest = std::mem_fn(&WebServerInterface::handleRootPageRequest);
    // error: conversion from 'std::_Mem_fn<void (WebServerInterface::*)()>' to non-scalar type 'WebServer::THandlerFunction' {aka 'std::function<void()>'} requested

WebServer::THandlerFunction fhandleRootPageRequest = (WebServer::THandlerFunction) std::mem_fn(&WebServerInterface::handleRootPageRequest);
    // error: no matching function for call to 'std::function<void()>::function(std::_Mem_fn<void (WebServerInterface::*)()>)'
```

Comment: Use a lambda function to call your member function.

Comment: Thanks John - I tweaked with: static void handleRootPageRequest()... which in turn required a similar tweak: static WebServer webServerCPP. File now compiles - useful progress. However, there's a new linker error: "undefined reference to `WebServerInterface::webServerCPP'" . Any hints on what this might mean?

Comment: ...and just after I posted this, I see your comment re. lambda function. I'll take a look into this next

Comment: I don't think static is the correct solution, You should use a lambda function as the duplicate suggests.

Comment: But if you want to use static then as with any global variable you need to define `webServerCPP`, at the moment you only have a declaration.